pyinstaller executable reads external file(s) at startup
I am developing an executable app with a GUI including help support using pyinstaller 5.7.0.
All the help is in a dictionary in one .py file which is imported.  I'd like to be able to keep the file from being part of the build and have the executable read the file when it starts so that I can make changes without having to rebuild the executable; similar to saving and recalling configurations in INI files.
I've read the pyinstaller documentation and searched the postings online but haven't found anything relevant.  I'd like to know if it's possible to read the .py file with 'Python stuff' in it before trying to do it using text or JSON format.
Maybe I don't understand the terminology.
